# Solve $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x^2 \ln{\frac{1+x}{x}})$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I've seen the solution to $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x^2 \ln{\frac{1+x}{x}})$ using L'Hopital and I was wondering if there's a way to find out the result without it. My initial attempt was outright stupid of me because I tried to substitute the limit of $\frac{\ln{(1+\frac{1}{x})}}{\frac{1}{x}}$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$ with $1$, which results in the initial limit being $0$. That's obviously false as I ignored the fact that I cannot do such a substitution when the limit is in an indeterminate form. That being said, how could you solve this limit without L'Hopital?

Comment: $\log(1+y)=y-y^2/2+O(y^3)$ when $|y|<1.$ Letting $y=1/x,$ since $\frac{x+1}x=1+\frac1x,$ you have: $$x-x^2\left(\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+ O\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)\right)=\frac12+O(1/x)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \bigg\{x - x^2 \, \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)\bigg \} $$
Now substitute $ x = \frac{1}{h}$

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \bigg\{\frac{1}{h} - \frac{1}{h^2}\, \ln\left(1+h\right)\bigg \} $$

Now using Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \bigg\{ \frac{1}{h} - \frac{1}{h^2} \left( h - \frac{h^2}{2} + \frac{h^3}{3} - \cdots \right) \bigg \} $$

Now first 2 terms will get cancelled and after applying limit,

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \bigg\{ \frac{1}{h} - \frac{1}{h} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{h}{3} + \frac{h^2}{4} - \cdots \bigg \} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: Applying the MacLaurin expansion is a stronger tool than the l'Hospital rule.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yeah! In fact, Taylor (Maclaurin) series expansions are our primary weapons. Sometimes when L'H rule sucks because it gives us long derivatives and there Taylor (Maclaurin) comes :)

Comment: Application of  l'Hopital rule to ${h-\ln(1+h)\over h^2}$ is very effective. There are no complicated derivatives and one application plus easy algebraic transformations are sufficient.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yeah! separating then applying L'H rule. I was just saying because I have encountered many limit sums where series expansions make our calculations easier mostly when we have function like arcsine, arctan in denominator. But we cannot deny how helpful L'H rule is and it's amazing when I watched 3B1B's video on this I understood how L'H rule works.

Comment: Sir, I have visited your website and got to know that you are research mathematician. I am in my undergrad. What I am asking is "How do you study for research?" I mean like I in college do problems. learn concepts, etc. And what math advice you would like to give me? Thank you!

Comment: Please do address me sir. Ryszard is fine. It is hard to answer your question. I just solve problems and study concepts necessary for solving them. The only advice I can give you: solve homework problems and simplify solutions to give impression, they were easy. Attend classes especially run by good lecturers.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you! I'll focus more on solving problems.

Answer (score 1):

The limit can be solved without using l'Hopital's rule and Taylor expansion, in fact:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-x^2 \log{\frac{1+x}{x}}\right)=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t-\log(1+t)}{t^2}$$
And the last limit is $1/2$ and can be prooven without l'Hopital's rule and Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Use substitution $e^t = \frac{x}{1 + x}$;

$$x - x^2\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right) \quad \overset{e^t = \frac{x}{1 + x}}{\longrightarrow} \quad \frac{1}{e^{-t} - 1} + \frac{t}{\left( e^{-t} - 1 \right)^2} = \frac{t + e^{-t} - 1}{\left( e^{-t} - 1 \right)^2} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ = \frac{te^{t} + 1 - e^{t}}{e^{t}\left( e^{-t} - 1 \right)^2} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ = \frac{te^{t} + 1 - e^{t}}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} - e^{\frac{t}{2}} \right)^2} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ = \frac{te^{t} + 1 - e^{t}}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} \right)^2 - 4} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ = \frac{te^{t} - e^{\frac{t}{2}}\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} - 2 \right) - 2e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} - 2 \right)\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ = \frac{te^{t} - 2e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} - 2 \right)\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} - \frac{e^{\frac{t}{2}}}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)}$$

As $x \to \infty, t \to 0$. WLOG assume $te^{\frac{t}{2}} + 1 \approx e^{t}$ for small $t$. (The intention behind this was to be able to factor the numerator while keeping the integrity of limit equivalent. Since, $\color{red}{x}e^{x}$ would not be factored easily, the goal was to approximate $\color{red}{x}e^{x} \approx \color{blue}{k}e^{\frac{x}{\color{blue}{c}}} + \color{blue}{p}$, where $k = 1$ was preferred, for small $t$).

Hence, from where we left off,

$$\frac{te^{t} - 2e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} - 2 \right)\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} - \frac{e^{\frac{t}{2}}}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ = \frac{e^{\frac{t}{2}} \left( te^{\frac{t}{2}} + 1 \right) - 3e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} - 2 \right)\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} - \frac{e^{\frac{t}{2}}}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ \approx \frac{e^{\frac{t}{2}}e^{t} - 3e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} - 2 \right)\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} - \frac{e^{\frac{t}{2}}}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} $$

Now, let $u = e^{\frac{t}{2}}$;

$$\frac{e^{\frac{t}{2}}e^{t} - 3e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} - 2 \right)\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} - \frac{e^{\frac{t}{2}}}{\left( e^{\frac{-t}{2}} + e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 2 \right)} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ \overset{u = e^{\frac{t}{2}}}{\longrightarrow} \frac{u^3 - 3u + 2}{\left( u^{-1} + u + 2 \right)\left( u^{-1} + u - 2 \right)} - \frac{u}{\left( u^{-1} + u + 2 \right)} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ = \frac{u^2 (u - 1)^2 (u + 2)}{\left( 1 + u^2 + 2u \right)\left( 1 + u^2 - 2u \right)} - \frac{u}{\left( u^{-1} + u + 2 \right)} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ = \frac{u^2 (u - 1)^2 (u + 2)}{(u + 1)^2(u - 1)^2} - \frac{u^2}{(u + 1)^2} \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ = \frac{u^2(u + 1)}{(u + 1)^2} = \frac{u^2}{u + 1}$$

As $x \to \infty \Rightarrow t \to 0 \Rightarrow u \to 1$

Hence and finally, $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{\lim\limits_{u \to 1}{\frac{u^2}{u + 1}} = \frac{1}{2}}$$